# How to do it better layout for d3.js like grid

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, layout, pipeline

I drew items with connections, but unfortunately it’s not quite successful to arrange them.
Now I have this picture:
[image]

I managed to arrange in groups but it is impossible to place interconnected elements on one line.
But I want to get this option:

[image]

Here is the current code:

```
var json = {
    "nodes": [
        {"group": 1, "featureId": "pMeter_StartSetId", "trigger": "trigger1"},
        {"group": 1, "featureId": "pMeter_ResetSetId", "trigger": "trigger2"},
        {"group": 1, "featureId": "fS___startFSPopup", "trigger": "trigger3"},
        {"group": 1, "featureId": "reSpins_stRSPopup", "trigger": "trigger4"},
        {"group": 1, "featureId": "jackpotIndication", "trigger": "trigger5"},
        {"group": 1, "featureId": "jackpotShowPopup", "trigger": "trigger6"},
        {"group": 2, "animId": "jI_UpdateIndicators"},        
        {"group": 2, "animId": "jI_JackpotShowPopup" },
        {"group": 2, "animId": "progressiveMeter_UpdateIndicators"},
        {"group": 2, "animId": "progressiveMeter_ResetSetFunc"},
        {"group": 2, "animId": "startFreeSpinsPopup"},
        {"group": 2, "animId": "startRespinsPopup"}
    ],
    "links": [
        {"source": 0, "target":  5 },
        {"source": 2, "target":  7 },
        {"source": 4, "target":  9 },
        {"source": 6, "target":  11},
        {"source": 8, "target":  1 },
        {"source": 10, "target": 3 }
    ]
}

    var main_row = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(json.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr("x", 50).attr("y", 50)
        .attr("width", 160)
        .attr("height", 80)
        .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 50).attr("y", 50)
            .attr("width", 16)
            .attr("height", 80)
            .style("fill","black");

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(json.nodes)
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(json.links).distance(300).strength(1))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(width / 2).y(height / 2)) 
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(1)) 
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(.1).radius(32).iterations(1))
        .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(0.5).x( d => x(d.group) ))
        .force("yPosition", d3.forceY(d => d.r === 20 ? 100 : 300))
        .force("xPosition", d3.forceX(d => d.r === 20 ? 100 : 300))
        .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(0.1).y( height/2 ))
        .on("tick", ticked);

    function ticked() {
        link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x + dx)
            .attr("y1", d => d.source.y + dy)
            .attr("x2", d => d.target.x + dx)
            .attr("y2", d => d.target.y + dy);
        main_row.attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" );

    }
```

Comment: erm why are you using force simulation in the first place?

Comment: Because this example is most used for cases with drawing links and graphs. And my connection may be one to three, etc.

Comment: force layout and graphs are orthogonal to each other. They're often used together because people want to have that automatic fluid spacing, not for rigid structure which you're seemingly after

Comment: if the connections are one-to-many (and not many-to-many), have a look at hierarchy / tree layout https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ok, but I also wanted the possibility of physics, so that it would be convenient to drag etc. And I found only for force simulation examples.